# Returning and instance of a Class given its .class (MyClass.class)

Tags: java

I have an enum that will hold my algorithms.  I cannot instantiate these classes because I need the application context which is only available once the application has started.  I want to load the class at runtime when I choose by calling getAlgorithm(Context cnx).

**How do I easily instantiate a class at runtime given its .class (and my constructor takes arguments)?  All my classes are subclasses of Algorithm.**

```
public enum AlgorithmTypes {
ALL_FROM_9_AND_LAST_FROM_10_ID(AlgorithmFactory.AlgorithmAllFrom9AndLastFrom10Impl.class),
ALL_FROM_9_AND_LAST_FROM_10_CURRENCY_ID(AlgorithmFactory.AlgorithmAllFrom9AndLastFrom10Impl.class),
DIVIDE_BY_9_LESS_THAN_100(AlgorithmFactory.AlgorithmAllFrom9AndLastFrom10Impl.class),
TABLES_BEYOND_5_BY_5(AlgorithmFactory.AlgorithmAllFrom9AndLastFrom10Impl.class);

private Class<? extends Algorithm> algorithm;

AlgorithmTypes(Class<? extends Algorithm> c) {
    algorithm = c;
}

public Algorithm getAlgorithm(Context cnx) {
    return //needs to return the current algoriths constructor which takes the Context Algorithm(Context cnx);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`java.lang.Class<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)** has all the magic you need, in particular you can use the `forName()` and `getConstructor()` methods to get the effect you want like below:

```
public Constructor getAlgorithm(Context cnx) {
    Class klass = Class.forName("YourClassName"));
    Constructor constructor = klass.getConstructor(cnx.getClass());
    return constructor;
}
```

If you want `getAlgorithm` to return an instance rather than just the constructor to invoke you can invoke the constructor:

```
public Algorithm getAlgorithm(Context cnx) {
    Class klass = Class.forName("YourClassName"));
    Constructor constructor = klass.getConstructor(cnx.getClass());
    return constructor.newInstance(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Class.[getConstructor()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) function in order to obtain the constructor, and then you can use Constructor.[newInstance()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) in order to instantiate the class, while passing arguments to the constructor.